# search a location and plot to map using leaflet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

Requirements: search a location and plot to map using leaflet?

I have a location that will be plot to the map as a marker using leaflet ie search option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[L.geoSearch](https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch) is a great plug-in that allows for geocoding addresses. Might help you with this.